# getpass() sets two strings the same?

Tags: c

I'm trying out `getpass()`, and I thought I'd try something:

```
char *key1 = getpass("K: ");
char *key2 = getpass("K: ");
if(key1 == key2) {

    printf("Good\n");

} else {

    printf("Bad\n");

}
```

If I write two different things in the two different fields, it will say "Good". I added a line to print the two strings, and it turns out they're both equal to whatever I type in the second one (typing "1" and "2" for key1 and key2 will result in both being equal to 2). What could be going on here?

Answer (score 2):

From the Linux man pages, `getpass()` returns a pointer to a static buffer, so every call to get pass will return the same address and the pointer stored in `key1` will always equal the pointer stored in `key2`.

> Return Value
>
> The function `getpass()` returns a pointer to a static buffer containing (the first PASS_MAX bytes of) the password without the trailing newline, terminated by a null byte ('\0'). This buffer may be overwritten by a following call. On error, the terminal state is restored, `errno` is set appropriately, and NULL is returned.

You will need to make a local copy of each string returned by `getpass()` can then use `(strcmp(key1Copy, key2Copy) == 0)` to see if they are equal.

Comment: +1, also note that `getpass()` is obsolete, it shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) to duplicate a "string" and [`strcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare two "strings" by content.

Try this:

```
char * key1 = strdup(getpass("K: ")); 
char * key2 = strdup(getpass("K: ")); 

if (0 == strcmp(key1, key2)) 
{
  printf("Good\n");
}
else
{
  printf("Bad\n");
}

free(key1);
free(key2);
```

Also please note that [getpass()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpass.3.html) **is obsolete** and shall **not** be used anymore!